# HTML - custom radio button not toggled if clicking the text

Tags: html, css, sass, radio-button

I built a custom `radio button` using this structure. However using this configuration I cant click the text to toggle the radio, any ideas why this is not working?

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input id="pefrormanceRadio" name="bonusRangeRadio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="pefrormanceRadio">
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    </label>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">test</span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by moving your text inside the label element.

Clicking a label will also click its associated form input. You can either associate a label and a form input with the 'for' HTML attribute (as per zmuci's answer) or by wrapping your input with the label element (which you are already doing).

In your case you were trying to click some text that was outside the label (hence not associated in any way with the input).

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input id="pefrormanceRadio" name="bonusRangeRadio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="pefrormanceRadio">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">test</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "connect" the text and input, you do that with `for` attribute added to `label` tag.

So your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="pefrormanceRadio" name="bonusRangeRadio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="pefrormanceRadio">
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio" for="pefrormanceRadio">Test</label>
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
</div>
```

Or if you can't change the HTML, Den Biswajit answer is the correct one. But you should be aware that from the semantic/accessible point of view, input should have a meaningful label.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using jquery

```
$("label").click(function(){
$("#pefrormanceRadio").attr('checked', 'checked'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add **custom-control-description** inside label and update css

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="pefrormanceRadio" name="bonusRangeRadio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="pefrormanceRadio">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">test</span>
  </label>
</div>
```